# single quote problem with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-replace-callback, single-quotes

I've searched extensively, but I don't find hints or solutions for my problem.
The problem is that I'm unable to match words with single quotes. Perhaps this is caused by server, php or mysql settings.
I like to know if I can work around this.

I'v got a live example here: [Fiddle with preg_replace_callback](https://3v4l.org/OGnFj)

```
<?php
$message = "1. test autotest test<br \>2. test auto's test<br \>3.test auto test ";
$message = preg_replace_callback("~( auto(?:'s)? )~si", function ($match)
    { return ' <a href="https://example.com">'.$match[1].'</a> '; }, $message, 1);
echo $message;
// here number 2 is correctly replaced, on my site number 3. Number 2 is not working on my site. I suspect the single quote is the problem on my site. Is there a workaround?
?>
```

Result:

1. test autotest test
2. test  [auto's](https://example.com)  test
3. test auto test

When I implement this code on my site, **auto's** is never matched. That's why I think it is caused by server, php or mysql settings. I like to know if I can work around this within my regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.
The single quote was stored in the database as `&#39;`
Replacing `~( auto(?:'s)? )~` with `~( auto(?:&#39;s)? )~` solved my problem.

Complete working code:

```
<?php
$message = "1. test autotest test<br \>2. test auto's test<br \>3.test auto test ";
$message = preg_replace_callback("~( auto(?:&#39;s)? )~si", function ($match)
    { return ' <a href="https://example.com">'.$match[1].'</a> '; }, $message, 1);
echo $message;
?>
```

Hint. Tip. So in similar cases check how a character is stored in your database and use that in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `1` at the end of preg_replace (it means substitue only once):

```
$message = preg_replace_callback("~( auto(?:'s)? )~si", function ($match)
    { return ' <a href="https://example.com">'.$match[1].'</a> '; }, $message);
//                                                                   here __^^^
```

Comment: No that's not  the problem. The message, 1 just makes sure only the first match is processed. First match in the example is auto's, on my site auto's is not recognized so the first match is auto. Just to make sure I tested without ,1 but it makes no difference.